# Inserting data in oracle apex (through a form into a table?)

Tags: forms, oracle-apex, development-environment

When programming i usually do everything myself and recycle code when needed so for once i decided to try out a development platform to speed up the process so i picked oracle apex- only to find myself suffering with overchoice

Normally if wanted the user to give me some data id just make a form and the data just ends up on my database, not hard.

[this isnt what i want to make, this is just for the sake of an example of the way one usually goes about this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKyZ1.png)

[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NorO8.jpg)

But now in oracle apex i dont even know if this is even the right way of asking end user to input data into a table, what should i do if -for example- i just want to make the user run some calculations and then store the results? Is there something specific that apex already has for this or do i do it myself normally

Any tutorials or the names of the functions i need to use would be helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe what you might want is Report with Form.

Its a setup the Page Wizard can make for you which is essentially exactly what you want. You select the table and columns, then it makes one page with a table of all entries, and you can click on an entry or click to make a new entry, and it opens up a form with the relevant page items which you input or edit, and then save.

Maybe a general APEX guide would be best for you since you are so new to it. Because if you know what is possible, then you might find different solutions to problems you have. I dont have a guide to recommend unfortunatelly, but I am sure you can find plenty on google, just make sure the version is correct, it doesent have to be for your exact version(there is a big difference pre 18 and post 18, less so with 19 and 20)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, APEX can be a bit overwhelming in the beginning. Your question is very generic so it is hard to give you a detailed answer. In general, if you have the data in a single record, then a form is the way to go (easiest is to start with report and from). If you need to modify certain column data after user submit, you can do that in processes or computations before submit.
Feel free to ask a question with your specific business requirement - you're pretty sure to get an answer here.